# HEAD detached branch git

Tags: git, branch, head

I'm relatively new to Git, I have the following problem.

I did a git checkout at this commit `76a474b` and I'm now in a detached HEAD. How can I make HEAD point back to the `redesign-ui` branch without creating a temporary branch?

```
karim@Karims-MacBook-Pro % git branch
* (HEAD detached at 76a474b)
  master
  redesign-ui
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a temporary branch if you just want HEAD to point to this branch `redesign-ui`. You can do a normal checkout to that branch :

```
git checkout redesign-ui
```

However, if you have made changes in the detached HEAD state and would like to keep track of it in the future, you can create a branch at this commit by doing :

```
git branch <branch-name>
# Commit the changes if any
```